# How to pass collection and access from method in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a simple class to test how to pass list of object into a method and access that list inside method.

```
class baseMakeUp {

    var Brand: String
    var Color: String
    var Rating: Int = 0

    init (Brand: String, Color: String) {
        self.Brand = Brand
        self.Color = Color
    }
}

var listOfBaseMakeUp = [baseMakeUp]()

listOfBaseMakeUp.append(baseMakeUp(Brand:"testA" , Color:"don't knowA"))
listOfBaseMakeUp.append(baseMakeUp(Brand:"testB" , Color:"don't knowB"))



for testObject in listOfBaseMakeUp {

    print(testObject.Brand)
}

func testMehod( listTempOb: [baseMakeUp] ) -> Void{

    for ob in listTempOb {
      print(ob.Brand)  
    }
}
```

But when I am accessing Brand property inside the **testMehod function** its showing **use of unresolved identifier 'testObject'**

I am from c#, so finding little bit awkward, anyone give me some resource link how to handle these?

Comment: I appreciate you come from C# but you should really adopt Swift code conventions. Classes should start with a capital letter and properties should start with a lowercase letter. More Info can be found here: [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: its just for a test purpose i mean without following any convention

Answer (score 1):

Your function is written wrong:

```
func testMehod( listTempOb: [baseMakeUp] ) -> Void{

    for ob in listTempOb {
      **print(testObject.Brand)**  
    }
}
```

`print(testObject.Brand)` should change to: `print(ob.Brand)`

Comment: yes i did a mistake. solved this working fine , thanks